# Cannot figure why NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

public class Punct {
    private float x, y;

```
public Punct ( float x, float y ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void changeCoords ( float x, float y ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void displayCoords() {
    System.out.println ( "( " + x + ", " + y + " )" );
}
```

}

public class Poligon {

```
Punct points[];

public Poligon ( int num, float values[] ) {
    points = new Punct[num];
    int j = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < num; ++i ) {
            points[i].changeCoords(values[j], values[j+1]);
            j+=2;   
    }
}

public void displayPoligon( int nr ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < nr; ++i ) {
        points[i].displayCoords();
    }
}
```

}

public class test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = 3;
    float val[] = new float[2*n];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 2*n; ++i ) {
        val[i] = i;
    }

    Poligon a = new Poligon(n, val);
    a.displayPoligon(n);
}
```

}

When I compile this code it returns me java.lang.NullPointerException to the line "             points[i].changeCoords(values[j], values[j+1]);" even though I've created the instance for points[].

Comment: You never seem to assign items to your array, and so you can't use any times until you do this first.

Comment: Aren't I allowed to do that "  for ( int i = 0; i < 2*n; ++i ) {
        val[i] = i;
    }" ?

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. You're trying to call a method on `points[i]` when you've assigned no objects to the array.

Comment: It's like you're trying to make an omelette with an empty egg carton. You first have to fill it with eggs to be able to use any eggs from it.

Comment: I am new in this programming language. Is there anything to do about the Punct array named points beside " points = new Punct[num];"?

Comment: `new Punct[num]` creates an *array* but does not create any `Punct` *objects*.  To do that, you will need to call `new Punct()` or `new Punct(x,y)` at some point.

Comment: I think I've got it, let me check. Thank you! All I had to do was to call the constructor instead of the method changeCoords. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use debugger to find such problems

2) Your error is in below code:

Before accessing objects in array by index, make sure that there is some object at all, so that you are not trying to change some values for non existing (null) object. I've added comments in below your code.

```
public Poligon(int num, float values[]) {
    points = new Punct[num]; -- here you created an EMPTY array, it will have a length, but it is without any objects yet 
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) { 
        points[i].changeCoords(values[j], values[j + 1]); // here is exception. You are trying to change Coords for NULL object
        j += 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an instance of `points[]`, but the array has no elements, so a specific element `points[i]` is null.

Answer (score 0):

you have declared array. you need to declare each member of array using new operator

`for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++)
{
  points[i] = new Punct();
}`